# How to make Flask Request wait till CronJob Executed

Tags: python, flask, cron

I have a use case where destructive CronJob should run every hour, session cleaning Background Task.

When I have a request being processed and CronJob is Active, this request fails. How to make this request delayed to initiate a new session until the CronJob Executed, takes 15 sec.

Code Sample

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/new_request", methods=["GET"])
@auth.login_required
def request():
/*
  Request Processing 
*/

sched = BackgroundScheduler(daemon=True)
sched.add_job(func=close_session, trigger="cron", hour="*")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sched.start()
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

What are the alternative solutions to make CronJob Executed safely without corrupting any in-progress requests?

Comment: this will add constant delay per each request, CronJob executed once every hour

Comment: In `@app.before_request`: check if the job is active and if yes, redirect to a "down for maintanance" page